# How to create new objects dynamically at runtime without hard coding them?

Tags: python, class, oop

I am new to python. I'm writing a testing application for another analytical tool. That tool outputs various kinds of files we call 'artifacts'. Each type of artifact is a data file of some kind.

I created a parent class called Artifact that has load() and compare() functions.

So, say I have two types of artifacts: cube and report. Each has an associated Cube and Report class, with functions that know how to read the respective data, and compare one to another (one cube to another cube and one report to another report).

Implementing that is all clear to me.

Here's my question: I'd like users to be able to implement their own new Artifacts that I'm not aware of now, and be able to load them via a config file.

The new child of Artifact would need to be a .py file, but I would like to not have to alter the code of the main test application. So I'd like the users to specify in a config file to use existing Cube and Report artifacts, as well as their newly defined artifact. For all artifacts do a load() and compare()

Can I do this without doing an explicit import of the new class, and without specify an Explicit call to it?

Can I just write

```
for c in Artifact classes:
    c.load()
    c.compare()
```

?  (that's obviously simplified, I hope it's clear)

Comment: So essentially you want to reference classes (that inherit from `Artifact`) based on user input? Such is `my_class = ./CustomArtifact.py` ? And YOUR code would need to operate on that class, and not the other way around?

Comment: Don't describe your code, show it to us!

Comment: You are looking to load modules dynamiaclly; check out the `importlib` module.

Comment: @CollinHeist - Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to add a subpackage to your project where new artifact processors are checked in as a new .py file. Add the import to `__init__.py` and it will load automatically.

```
myproject
    __init__.py
    artifacts.py
    artifactsdb
        __init__.py
        cube.py
        report.py
```

artifacts.py

```
class Artifacts:

    def load(self):
        pass

    def compare(self):
        pass

def enum_artifacts():
    for art in Artifacts.__subclasses__():
        art().load()
        art().compare()
```

artifactsdb/**init**.py

```
from .cube import cube
from .report import report
```

artifacts/cube.py

```
from ..artifacts import Artifacts
class cube(Artifacts):
    pass
```

Comment: Uhm.. good idea, but as you wrote them `compare` and `load` aren't class methods and `art` in `for art in Artifacts.__subclasses__` is a class, not an instance. Just create `obj = art()` and call the methods on `obj`

Comment: @Pynchia - Uhm, OP doesn't give a solid definition of what `load` and `compare` should be, so I just sketched in something vague. For instance, how should the code select which subclass to use? Some rule about file names? A generic loader that then selects subtypes? Try them all until one doesn't crash? I don't know, so just sketched it in. I neglected to call `__subclass__` in the example. I did test but seem to have missed a few bits and bobs while pulling it together.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I think I generally understand the suggestion here, but I'll need to try to implement this to work through it.  My python isn't strong enough yet to just visualize this.  But it's a very helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The config file could be a python module, that imports the new artifact classes. If your users are able to write their own python classes, they shouldn't have a problem editing such a config file:

- in userconfig.py:

```
# import user artifact classes:
from myartifact import NewArtifact

# add user artifacts to the list "user_artifacts"
user_artifacts = [
    NewArtifact
]
```

- in your main code:

```
import userconfig

for c in userconfig.user_artifacts:
    # load and compare
```